# LibGDX - how to pass texture attribute to shader for sphere

Tags: android, 3d, opengl-es-2.0, libgdx

I have next vertex and fragment shaders:

```
String vertexShader = "attribute vec4 a_position;    \n"
    + "attribute vec4 a_color;\n" 
    + "attribute vec2 a_texCoords;\n"
    + "uniform mat4 u_worldView;\n" 
    + "varying vec4 v_color;"
    + "varying vec2 v_texCoords;"
    + "void main()                  \n"
    + "{                            \n"
    + "   v_color = vec4(1, 1, 1, 1); \n"
    + "   v_texCoords = a_texCoords; \n"
    + "   gl_Position =  u_worldView * a_position;  \n"
    + "}                            \n";
String fragmentShader = "#ifdef GL_ES\n"
    + "precision mediump float;\n"
    + "#endif\n"
    + "varying vec4 v_color;\n"
    + "varying vec2 v_texCoords;\n"
    + "uniform sampler2D u_texture;\n"
    + "void main()                                  \n"
    + "{                                            \n"      
     + "  gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoords);\n"
    + "}";
```

How can I set attributes `a_position`, `a_color` and `a_texCoords` for 3D sphere?
To set uniform I use:

```
texture.bind();
shader.begin();
shader.setUniformMatrix("u_worldView", matrix);
shader.setUniformi("u_texture", 0);
//HOW TO?
//shader.setAttributef("a_texture", value1, value2, value3, value4)
mesh.render(shader, GL20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
shader.end();
```

Comment: Have you checked ``ShaderProgram.setVertexAttribute(...)`` variants already?

Comment: In libgdx the mesh should be doing that. When you create it, one way or another, you specified the attributes it has (there are some defaults).

Comment: I create mesh by using ObjLoader. Could you explain me how to do this?

Comment: ObjLoader does that for you. May be you can check that your .obj file has texturing info. or you can use a debugger - Insert a breakpoing just before the mesh.render() call, and inspect your mesh attributes. It should have a varying attribute with alias "v_texCoords" (otherwise it wont work).
is the mesh rendered black or what? Try to use a spriteBatch and draw a sprite with that texture, just to make sure it's loading correctly.

Comment: I use libgdx-0.9.7. I tried to load object `mesh = ObjLoader.loadObj(Gdx.files.internal("objects/earth_small.obj").read());`. I checked obj file - it contains v vn vt f But mesh rendered black! I even copied .mtl file to the same asset directory

Comment: Should I use `texture.bind();` and `shader.setUniformi("u_texture", 0);` if I use ObjLoader? Would be better to see an example

Comment: yes, you should do that. You could call texture.bind(0) to be sure, but that's the default anyway. The main problem here is that the code seems to be ok (i also took a look at your other post which has more detail). Try to render that texture and see if it works just to remove some possibilities.

Comment: Have you any example how to load and render textured object using shaders? I really need it. I can't find any examples.